# Number of roots of $\cot x - \tan x = a$

Tags: trigonometry

> If $a \in \mathbb{R}$, number of roots of $\cot x - \tan x = a$ in first quadrant are...

My approach:
$$\cot x - \tan x = a$$
$$1 - \tan²x = a\tan x$$
$$\tan²x + a \tan x - 1 = 0$$
Let c & d be the roots.
$$\tan c × \tan d = -1$$
$$\tan c = - \cot d = \cot(-d)$$
'd' lies either in 2nd or in 4th quadrant- doesn't matter.
Now 'c' lies either in 3rd quadrant or in 1st quadrant.

Now, I don't know what should be the next step.
Answer is $1$.

Comment: Note that $\cot x - \tan x = 2\cot 2x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$\cot x - \tan x = 2\cot 2x$$

Graph of $y=2\cot 2x$ is monotonic for $x \in (0, \pi/2)$ and $y \in (-\infty, \infty)$.

Hence unique solution for any real $a$.

Answer (score 0):

$$a=\cot x-\tan x=\cdots=2\cot2x$$

$$\implies\tan2x=\dfrac2a$$

$2x=n\pi+\arctan\dfrac2a$ where $n$ is any integer

We need $$0<2x<\pi\ \ \ \  (1)$$

For $a>0,$

$$ n\pi<2x<n\pi+\dfrac\pi2$$

By $(1), n<1$ and $n>-1\implies n=0,0<2x<\dfrac\pi2\implies$ exactly one solution

What if $a<0?$

Comment: Not understood that why for a>0, nπ < 2x < nπ+(π/2).

Comment: @Sangeeta, https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.teachoo.com/amp/7518/1177/Principal-Value/category/Finding-pricipal-value/

Comment: So, if a<0 then nπ-π/2 < 2x < nπ. Similarly that will give 1 solution in 1st quadrant. Am I right or wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Let $tx= \tan x$

$$1/tx-tx-a =0,\quad (tx)^2 +a\; tx -1=0\;$$

two real roots of quadratic equation of positive discriminant

$$ tx=\tan x= \dfrac{-a\pm \sqrt{a^2+4}}{2}$$

So a doubly infinite set of roots due to $\pm$  for each $ \tan x$ function intersection solution.

Equivalently the roots can be ordered together by a single inverse function

$$ 2 \cot 2x =a;\quad  2x = \tan^{-1}\frac{2}{a}+ k \pi; \quad x = \dfrac12 \tan^{-1}\frac{2}{a}+ k \pi/2. $$

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that "in the first quadrant" means $0\lt x\lt\pi/2$, note that $\cot x$ decreases from $\infty$ to $0$ on $[0,\pi/2]$ while $\tan x$ increases from $0$ to $\infty$, and thus $\cot x-\tan x$ decreases from $\infty$ to $-\infty$, and therefore, for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$, there is exactly one value of $x$ in the first quadrant for which $\cot x-\tan x=a$.

Remark: This answer tacitly uses the Intermediate Value Theorem for continuous functions (and tacitly uses the fact that $\cot x$ and $\tan x$ are continuous on $(0,\pi/2)$). If you don't have all that at your disposal, you can only conclude from the (strictly) decreasing nature of $\cot x-\tan x$ that there is *at most one* value of $x$ for which $\cot x-\tan x=a$, and you need to do something along the lines of the other answers here to show that a solution exists.